# Down-rev kernel doesn't do anything

Tags: 16.04, kernel, 15.04, hibernate

I am running Ubuntu-Mate 16.04 currently with kernel 4.13.0 64-bit on an Hp2510 notebook. Hibernation is much worse (slower on 64-bit and fails on the 32-bit version) on this than on 15.04 Ubuntu-desktop. I think the kernel is responsible. To find the point where hibernation became bad I want to down-rev the kernel (I haven't tried up-revving from 15.04 yet). I have used kmpd.py to retrieve and load kernel version 4.10.0. It seems to succeed except for a warning about missing i915 firmware. However, the kernel version doesn't change even after rebooting. Is this because down-revving doesn't work? Is it because of the missing i915 firmware (in which case, how do I provide it; the python script doesn't seem to provide any mechanism to address this)?

Comment: do you have a menu at boot .. if not it may be that the original kernel is set to default and you will need to edit the `/etc/default/grub` file to enable the menu so you have a choice to select the older kernel .. or edit it to select the older kernel by default (bit more difficult)

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is correct. Kernel selection is not on the main GRUB menu, as I expected, but under "Advanced options for Ubuntu".

Comment: glad you found what you needed :)

Comment: Another helpful hint is that the installed alternate kernel doesn't show up in the GRUB menu until you run update-grub. I wasted time live-editing the menu until I realized that I only needed to do this simple step.